# Variance and mean of a bernoulli

Tags: probability, variance, means, bernoulli-numbers

Let ${X_i}$ be a sequence of iid bernoulli random variables sucht that $P\{X_i = 1\} = p$ and $P\{X_i = 0\} = 1-p$ and let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Calculate variance and mean of $\frac{S_n}{n}$

I'm pretty sure that the mean is $p$. But the variance come to me as $-p$ and that's not possible.

$\mathbb E[X] = 1\times p + 0\times(1-p) = p$.

$\mathbb E[X^2] = 1^2 + p + 0 = p.$

$\mathsf{Var}(X_i) = \mathbb E[X^2] - (\mathbb E[X])^2 = p - p^2 = -p$.

Comment: Hint: By independence the variance of the sum equals the sum variances: $$\mathsf{Var}(X_1+\cdots+X_n)=\mathsf{Var}(X_1)+\cdots+\mathsf{Var}(X_n)$$If you know $\mathsf{Var}S_n$ then it is not difficult to find $\mathsf{Var}(S_n/n)$.

Comment: The problem is that var Sn comes to me -p since the second moment is p - p^2 which is the mean square.

Comment: Then edit and show your calculation. The flaw can be demasked then. That is according to the policy of this site.

Comment: Sorry for that. DOne!

Comment: $\mathbb EX^2-(\mathbb EX)^2=p-p^2=pq$ where $q=1-p$.

Comment: so the final is $\frac{p*(1-p)}{n}$ ?

Comment: Yes it is.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Part 1:**

For any $i$, there are

$$\mathbb{E}[X_i]=1\times p +0\times (1-p)=p,$$

and

$$Var[X_i]=\mathbb{E}[X_i^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X_i])^2=[1^2\times p+0^2\times (1-p)]-p^2=p(1-p).$$

Since $0\le p\le 1$, we have $Var[X_i]=p(1-p)\ge 0.$

---

**Part 2:**

Since $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, there are

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{S_n}{n}\right]=\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[S_n\right]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\left[X_i\right]=\frac{1}{n}\times n\times p=p,
$$

and

$$
Var\left[\frac{S_n}{n}\right]=\frac{1}{n^2}Var\left[S_n\right]=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^nVar\left[X_i\right]=\frac{1}{n^2}\times n\times p\times (1-p)=\frac{p(1-p)}{n}.
$$